# (先生に)お礼を申し上げます。

Tags: honorifics

(先生に)お礼を申し上げます。

Hello can someone tell me how this phrase is to be used?
Do I say it to the teacher or is this a phrase to use with a 3rd person talking about a teacher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That phrase is basically used "to the teacher".

**Example:**

Hey teacher, thanks to you I got a job. **I hereby express my gratitude (to you right now).**

Similar when you apologize - お詫び申し上げます = I hereby express my apologies.

[This post may be related and helpful.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58180/the-different-usage-between-%E8%87%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-and-%E7%94%B3%E3%81%97%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%92%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-interms-of-%E8%A3%9C%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/)