# The use of 申し上げる and 申す

Tags: keigo

According to Jisho.com, 申す　and 申し上げる　are both kenjougo. From what I can tell, the meanings are also very similar, if not identical.

However, the words are not interchangeable. We can use 申す (not 申し上げる)　in sentences like ケイトと申します. And we can't use 申す instead of 申し上げる in どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます.

Though it's easy to memorize the phrases, I'd like to understand the two verbs better. How exactly are they similar and different? When can and can't we use each of them?

Thank you!

Comment: See answer [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/28576/why-is-the-phrase-%e3%81%94%e9%80%a3%e7%b5%a1%e7%94%b3%e3%81%97%e3%81%82%e3%81%92%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-linguistially-correct/28597#28597) . Highly related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [敬語「申す」の意味と使い方、類語「申し上げる／おっしゃる」との違い](https://eigobu.jp/magazine/mousu-2#heading-135797) ,

> 「申{もう}す」は「言{い}う」の丁重語{ていちょうご}（謙譲語{けんじょうご}２）です。丁重語{ていちょうご}（謙譲語{けんじょうご}２）とは、聞き手に対して自分の行為をへりくだって表現することで、相手を立てる表現です。

「申{もう}す」is courtesy form of 「言{い}う」, and the expression is to express what you are doing in a reserved way to the listener to looking up to the listener.

They follow

> 「丁重語」は、後ろに「ます」という丁寧語をつけて使用することが基本です。したがって「申す」を使用する際も、丁寧語「ます」を付けて「〜と申します」という形で使用します。

So,「申{もう}す」 has to change into the 「申{もう}します」　with the polite suffix 「ます」。

Thus,

> ケイトと申{もう}します

this is saying the name "ケイト" to the listener in a reserved way to look up to the listener.

They move onto 「申{もう}し上{あ}げる」.

> 「申{もう}す」は、「申{もう}し上{あ}げる」で謙譲語{けんじょうご}（謙譲語{けんじょうご}１）になります。「謙譲語{けんじょうご}」（謙譲語{けんじょうご}１）とは、「相手に向かう自分の行為をへりくだって言うことで、行為の向かう相手に敬意を示す」表現方法です。

So, 「申{もう}し上{あ}げる」is humble form of 「申{もう}す」, and the expression is to saying what you are doing in a reserved way for the partner to show the respect to the partner.

> どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます.

So this is greeting itself is expressed in a reserved way to show the respect to the partner.

They also explains the etymology of 「もしもし」 on the phone call is 「申{もう}す」. Telephone operator used to say 「申します、申します」in order not to be rude to the listner, however it was hard to pick up the sound, it has become contracted into 「もしもし」.

> **電話の「もしもし」は「申す申す」が語源**
>
> 電話交換手は繋いでいる相手に失礼のないよう「申し上げます」という意味で「もしもし」と言っていました。これが始まりとされています。明治時代以前は「もし」と使われていましたが、だんだん電話が普及するにつれからは、電話の音が聞き取りづらいということもあって、電話交換手が「申し、申し」「申します、申します」と二度送り返すようになりました。「申します、申します」または「申す、申す」と言っていたのが、省略されて「もしもし」に変化しました。

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The origin of もしもし　is really interesting! Thank you for sharing the information!

Comment: Wow, I never knew 謙譲語 could be even further categorised into 謙譲語1 and 謙譲語2! There are just so many polite forms!

Comment: @Sweeper I didn't know either. Just 10 years ago so, it seemed to have changed. According to, [敬語は5種ある!【尊敬語,謙譲語,丁重語,丁寧語,美化語】違いと使い分け | 言葉の救急箱](https://99bako.com/1752.html) かつて敬語は【尊敬語、謙譲語、丁重語】の3種類でした。
しかし、**2007年**（平成19年）に文化審議会が答申した「敬語の指針」によって、2017年（平成29年）現在、敬語は【尊敬語、謙譲語、丁重語、丁寧語、美化語】の5種類に分類されています。