# The idol used "お仕事" to refer to her own job. Is that appropriate?

Tags: honorifics

I saw a dialogue in Japanese drama. The context of the dialogue is that an elderly female reporter is interviewing a young female idol who has just become popular. The dialogue is as follows:

> Interviewer:  今お仕事お忙しそうですね。(It sounds like you are busy with your work right now.) 
> The idol interviewed:  はい、でも**お仕事**はすごく楽しいですね。(Yes, but I really enjoy my job.)

The idol uses "お仕事" to refer to her own job. Is that appropriate?

Or is the scriptwriter trying to show that she was new, so she is not proficient in honorifics?

I thought お仕事 means 'your job', and only refers to other people's work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that usage is fine. お仕事 in that context is being used as a 美化語, which you can safely use to refer to something that belongs to yourself. お仕事 like this is not even an honorific (尊敬語) in the first place.

- [Terminology: Does the term 美化語 include all ご・お・etc. prefixes, or only ones outside of a 敬語 context?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86215/5010)

Actually, お仕事 is a word that lies in a gray area between 尊敬語 and 美化語. In very formal situations, like in job interviews, a few strict people may say お仕事 should be used only as a 尊敬語. That said, no one would consider this a problem in a casual interview with an idol.

Comment: In particular, I interpret the use of お仕事 here as paying respect to the *job itself* (to express how much she appreciates and values it).  It suggests that it's not just "any old job" to her, it is a special job which she is particularly happy to be able to have, etc.